# I need to change a javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I made an onclick popup redmore button for my sidebar text widget in wordpress just copied and pasted this code I found [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/b68Xb/). I did some little changes and everything worked fine.

The problem occurred when I had to make more onclick popups like that one for the rest of the sidebar widgets, exactly the same popup with same values but with different img and content text.

The problem is both "redmore" buttons in the first widget and in the second one link to the same thing - so it will open the same one no matter which redmore button you click -

[this is the website](http://www.risingher.com/) check out the first two items in the right sidebar.

Since I don't know much about Javascript, I'm asking you if you can help me changing the javascript tag link in the code in order to link to another different popup and not the same one - and let me understand how to change it since I have to make a few popups.

Comment: Include code when linking to JSFiddle. (And in general when you want help with some code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the Id attribute of the Contents for eg

```
<div id="light2" class="white_content">
<div id="fade2" class="black_overlay">
```

for the second pop up and change the javascript of the second read more text to

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light2').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade2').style.display='block'">here</a>
```

Same should be applied to all other pop ups.

Here i have changed the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d47anh3x/)

Comment: You could mark it as correct if it solved the issue :) .

Comment: yeah of course, but I'm new here, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the id for every popup Like

```
getElementById('fade')
getElementById('light')
```

[the first]

```
getElementById('fadesec')
getElementById('lightsec')
```

[the second] 
And so on.. 
 same thing on html content, don't just copy,  change ids

Example two:

```
<p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('lightsec').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fadesec').style.display='block'">here</a></p>
    <div id="lightsec" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content. <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('lightsec').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fadesec').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
    <div id="fadesec" class="black_overlay"></div>
```